# How to call GEOS error handlers provided during initialization (initGEOS)?

Tags: geos, debugging, c

From what I learned, when using GEOS in C/C++, it should be initialized first using `initGEOS` :

```
extern void GEOS_DLL initGEOS(GEOSMessageHandler notice_function,
         GEOSMessageHandler error_function);
```

, which takes two error handling functions `notice_function`, `error_function`.

My question is:

*How can these two handler functions be accessed and called in C?* (e.g. when one wants to print some notice messages while debugging an existing GEOS function)

I can't seem to find the documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be `GEOSContextHandle_HS::ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...)`. An example of calling the notice/error functions seems to be in the source code, e.g. for [GEOSWKTWriter_destroy](https://cvvergara.github.io/GEOS/geos__c_8cpp_source.html#l01007):

```
 void
 GEOSWKTWriter_destroy(WKTWriter *Writer)
 {
      GEOSWKTWriter_destroy_r( handle, Writer );
 }
```

in which `handle` is a global variable.

```
GEOSContextHandle_t handle
```

Then, this handle is used to call `ERROR_MESSAGE` e.g.:

```
char* GEOSWKTWriter_write_r(GEOSContextHandle_t  extHandle,
... )   
{
    //...
    GEOSContextHandleInternal_t *handle = 0;
    handle = reinterpret_cast<GEOSContextHandleInternal_t*>(extHandle);
    if ( 0 == handle->initialized )
    {
    return NULL;
    }

    try
    {
       //...
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
    handle->ERROR_MESSAGE("%s", e.what());
    }
    //...
 }
```